What is this US(?) Terminal or Screen?
Watching a WSJ-Segment about Airline-Loyalty-Programs I stumbled over this picture of what seems to be a room full of desks (*1) with two rather large terminals or screens upfront:

Does anyone know or have a trace about those terminals/screens?
It may originate from the late 70s/early 80s. Hard to say if they are terminals, or stand alone screens. It's hard to say, but they seem to be mounted to a rather large, fitting base, which would make a terminal (at least a special output only one) more likely.
What made me itch is an uncanny likenesses to the first PET prototype and a little less to its later incarnation:

[Picture taken from Chuck Hutchins blog entry about the Prototype]

*1 - Hard to tell ich accounting, phone hotline, booking or similar service as such setup has been used in many companies for many purpose all around the world since the late 1960s.

Lear Siegler ADM 42 terminal
Using google lens on this photo finds it's a stock image that is also used e.g. in the this New York Times article (also available via archive.org), where a larger part of the terminals is visible:

And there you can read that it is an Lear Siegler ADM 42 terminal.
This kind of design was widespread at this time, so it's no surprise that others like the PET prototype look similar.

re "widespread" - indeed, see the DEC VT05.

My boss selected the ADM42 for our office Alpha Micro system (10 terminals) in the '80s because he said it looked like Star Trek. No driver was available. He didn't care, make it work, he said. I got the source code for a Hazeltine 1500 terminal driver, learned WD16 assembler and adapted the driver using stone knives and bear skins. It worked.

@MTA: I'd rather say it looks like "Dark Helmet"'s helmet (Spaceballs)

@MTA so fancy, we were still in the bone clubs and grass loincloths at the time.

I wonder whether the stock photo was in fact showing an airline's office.  If so, I also wonder whether Lear Siegler leveraged their connection to the aviation industry (from predecessor company Lear Avionics) in selling the terminals to commercial airlines.

@Theodore I wouldn't be surprised if it's not showing an airline's office... and Sabre would have used IBM terminals.
